# ffmpeg command generates never stops

Tags: ffmpeg, overlay

I am overlaying 2 series of images on a video but command never stops execution until I I force stop process my command is as below

```
    ffmpeg -y -i vid.mp4 -loop 1 -i img_%d.png -loop 1 -i img1_%d.png -strict -2 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=0:0 [tmp];[tmp][2:v] overlay=50:50:shortest=1:enable='between(t,1,5)'"-codec:a copy out.mp4
```

I don't understan where is the mistake in command it just runs forever suppose i give 3minutes video as input then command outpot show length after 3 minutes like 4 mintues and greater and never stops execution

Comment: You should always include the complete console output from your command. The info it provides is always helpful in making an accurate answer.

Comment: hey  @LordNeckbeard every time you just say to include console out put but console output is normal as usual so i didn't included it if output shows some error then it is help full my console output is about 2000 lines and they are just messages of how much encoding is done so i didn't  included it

Comment: You can always trim lines that repeat numerous times, but the output always helps and can allow us to provide an answer faster.

Comment: ok buddy next time i will keep this thing in mind your answer solved my problem bro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `shortest=1` to your first overlay because `[1:v]` has an infinite duration due to using `-loop 1`:

```
ffmpeg -y -i vid.mp4 -loop 1 -i img_%d.png -loop 1 -i img1_%d.png -filter_complex \
"[0:v][1:v]overlay=shortest=1[tmp]; \
 [tmp][2:v]overlay=50:50:shortest=1:enable='between(t,1,5)',format=yuv420p" \
-codec:a copy out.mp4
```

- I removed `0:0` from your first overlay because those are the default values for `x` and `y` placement.
- I removed `-strict -2` because I see no usage of experimental encoders here.
- I added `format=yuv420p` at the end of your filtergraph to ensure the H.264 output uses YUV 4:2:0 chroma subsampling so it will play in QuickTime, WMP, and other crippled players.

Comment: Hey buddy thnx for your answer this solved my problem

Comment: I want to vote up but sorry i have no such reputation over here so i accepted youranswer

Comment: @user3269550 Good to hear it worked for you.